# Show a group $G$ forms a group under the multiplication "*"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

Let $e$ be an element of group $(G,\cdot)$

$(a)$ Show that the set $G$ forms a group under the multiplication
$$"*":G \times G \rightarrow G ; (x,y) \mapsto xe^{-1}y.$$
$(b)$ Show that the group $(G,*)$ with multiplication given by (a) is isomorphic to the oringinal group structure $(G, \cdot)$ on $G$.

My proof:

We're given that $(G,*)$ is closed under multiplication since $(G,\cdot)$ is a group and so $xe^{-1}y \in G$.  Similarly we must show that there exists an identity element $E_{G} \in G$.  Consider the following $$x*e=xe^{-1}e=xe_{G}=x$$
and so $e_{G}=e$

Next we must show $G$ contains inverses so $y=ex^{-1}e$ then,
$$x*y=xe^{-1}ex^{-1}e=xe_{G}x^{-1}e=xx^{-1}e=e_{G}e=e$$
For part $(b)$ I am unsure how to show they are isomorphic, I was thinking maybe finding a suitable group homomorphism and that would imply they are isomorphic.  I included my proof of part $(a)$ just to verify it is correct, any help on part $(b)$ is appreciated!

Comment: In your last proof for (a), there's a problem: $xx^{-1}$ is the identity element from the original group operation, not for the new one.

Comment: ah yes thanks for pointing that out, I should find a $y$ that such that $x*y=e$ correct?

Comment: Yep.  But, given that you know how to find $y$ so that $x*y=\text{id}$, and $\text{id}\cdot e=e$, I bet you can fix that pretty easily. :-)

Comment: Yep you are very right $y$ should equal $ex^{-1}e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (b), you want to show there is an isomorphism $\varphi: G\to G$ such that for all $a,b \in G$,
$$\varphi(a  b) = \varphi(a) * \varphi(b) = \varphi(a)e^{-1}\varphi(b).$$

Notice that we want to define $\varphi$ in a way that "cancels out" the $e^{-1}$ in the formula. Notice if we define $\varphi(x) = xe$, then
$$\varphi(ab) = (ab)e = abe$$
and
$$\varphi(a) * \varphi(b) = \varphi(a)e^{-1}\varphi(b) = (ae)e^{-1}(be) = a(ee^{-1})be = abe$$
and thus,
$$\varphi(a  b) = \varphi(a) * \varphi(b)$$
as desired.

Comment: Very nice solution, thanks a lot! +1